# Работа с чужими окнами WinApi

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, pywinauto, win32gui

Не могу разобраться как можно работать с чужими окнами в скрытом режиме. Для примера возьму окно Steam Login(Окно авторизации Steam). Spy++, SWAPY и т.д. видят только основное окно класса vguiPopupWindow[image: введите сюда описание изображения], без его элементов. Я знаю, что могу использовать click_input() от pywinauto и keyboard.send_keys(), но не могу найти информацию о том, что мне нужно для работы с данным типом окн в фоне.

Answer (score 1):

В фоне можно делать не все действия, и это часто зависит от приложения. Если элементы на окне не видны, надо использовать `Application(backend="uia")` как минимум и смотреть иерархию в Inspect.exe (тула из Windows SDK) или через функцию `.dump_tree()` у спецификации окна верхнего уровня. Или есть Python приложение на PyQt5 под названием [py_inspect](https://github.com/pywinauto/py_inspect), которое есть простой аналог Spy++/Inspect.exe. Оно умеет переключаться между бэкендами.

Конкретные подсказки по silent методам есть в [Remote Execution Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html) в пункте "Tricks to run automation on a locked machine". Ну, или можно вообще подумать о вынесении задачи на удалённую машину. Там достаточно полный сборник рецептов, которые смогли нарыть пользователи и я сам.

P.S. Кстати, `.dump_tree()` стал быстрее, и кое-какой полезный ре-факторинг есть вот в этой ветке (будущий major release, можно пощупать в качестве раннего тестирования при желании, даже на Линуксе кое-что дышит с получением детальных текстов):

```
pip uninstall -y pywinauto
pip install https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/atspi.zip
```

Несмотря на ранний статус, юнит тесты 100% проходят в облаке и покрывают 95% кода.